# Designing template

Tags: color, templates, article, documentclass-writing

This is an important question for me and any help would be great.

I want to design my regular assignments/submissions in LaTeX. I previously typed them in MS-Word which gave me enough options to customise the look and feel of the document. But LaTeX doesn't give me complete options as such to create text boxes, coloured headers, etc. I don't want to use the default black and white option as its getting too simple. I don't want to use MS-Word for a lot many reasons (which you can guess).

For example, I want to get a document class like [wiley-article](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scandinavian-journal-of-statistics/bgpgpnwdjdzv#.Wr6OwCmFPIU). But many of the options therein are useless for me and I can't get rid of them (removing them throws errors).

Can you suggest me a way how to tweak such documents or make a new one?

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: Look at [tcolorbox package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Your question is very broad, so also take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks! Any help for the custom look of authors and title?

Comment: You can take a look at the `titling`  package.

Comment: @Bernard can you please post this as an answer? This solved my problem.

Comment: If that solved your problem, the question is more than unclear. I think it is too broad anyways.

Comment: @Johannes_B Sir, I told him so because I think this was the best I could get. `titling` package could solve my issue to the extent that I could remove some details. There are more issues like removing correspondence address, etc. but seems like these details and source codes are proprietary and not opensource.
Moreover, I'm just an undergrad student and still haven't completely understood ways of communication here. So, please pardon me for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the `titling`  package, which is done to customise the `\maketitle` command.
It defines one length: `\droptitle`  for the positioning of the title on the page, six commands: `\pretitle`, `\posttitle`, `\preauthor`, `\postauthor`, `\predate`, `\postdate`, and four hooks: `\maketitlehooka`, … , `\maketitlehookd` for additional elements to `\maketitle`.

From the documentation:

> The \maketitle command as defined by the titling package is essentially
>
> \renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
>
> \vspace*{\droptitle}
>
> \maketitlehooka
>
> {\pretitle \title \posttitle}
>
> \maketitlehookb
>
> {\preauthor \author \postauthor}
>
> \maketitlehookc
>
> {\predate \date \postdate}
>
> \maketitlehookd
>
> }

Comment: Having read the question just now, I think titling would be the last thing the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I don't know. The O.p. said it solved his/her problem. Anyway I posted a summary of what can be done  with this package because I thought it might be useful to other people.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just went over [link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280) and this too helped.
I think I really need to learn ways of this site.